gênero de termos matemátcos: divergências luso-brasileiras
integral é um termo matemático que no português brasileiro tem gênero feminino (a integral) enquanto que no português europeu tem gênero masculino (o integral).  Existem outros exemplos de termos matemáticos ou científicos que têm gêneros diferentes entre o português brasileiro e o português europeu?

Boa pergunta, não me recordo de nenhum outro no momento.
